# RESTful account selection controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In my app, after a user logs in, he is redirected to the AccountsSelection controller. In there, I have an index action that basically will get all the potential accounts a user can use, and display them in a index view.

```
def index
  @accounts = current_user.eligible_accounts
end
```

In that page the user can click in one of the accounts, and that should go to one of the actions in the controller, that will set this in the session:

```
def show
  session[:selected_account] = params[:account_id]
  redirect_to account_path
end
```

Right now I have made that action to be show (so the selection of the account is doing a GET request, but I am not sure if this is a RESTful way of approaching this). From my point of view this is not a PUT/POST because I am not changing any resource or creating any resource, but it seems weird to be using the show action to just set a session.

What would be a proper way of handling this? It is correct to use show?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use session in this case. So the standard approach is to create a before_action to set the account_id.
Use like this:

```
before_action :set_account, only: [:show]
```

and create the function in private as:

```
 private
 def set_account
    account_id = params[:account_id]
 end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to persist the selected account through the session of the user. My question is related on RESTful choice.

Comment: Yes using Get request for show action is Restful way in rails.

Comment: Moreover, use redirect_to account_path(session[:selected_account]) to redirect.